# Does Xamarin.Android support MIDI?

Tags: xamarin.android, midi

The Android.Media.Midi has been supported since API level 23, but there's no documentation about this. Does any one know or has used this feature of xamarin? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Android.Media.Midi is supported in Xamarin.Android.
I haven`t working code yet, but you can start with

```
if (!PackageManager.HasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FeatureMidi)) throw new NotSupportedException("Midi");
var midiManager = (MidiManager) GetSystemService(MidiService);
var midiDevInfos =(MidiDeviceInfo[]) midiManager.GetDevices();
```

You must define class implementing interface IOnDeviceOpenedListener to try openning midi device and get its midi ports.
Coding midi is a little bit tricky with only Android Midi API documentation.